# Syntax highlighting in listings for C# that it looks like in Visual Studio

Tags: listings, highlighting, syntax

Community,

I want to get my C# `listings` syntax highlighted like in Visual Studio but I did not get it so far.

Here's an image of the syntax highlighting of Visual Studio:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstloadlanguages{% Check Dokumentation for further languages ...
%[Visual]Basic
%Pascal
C,
C++,
csh,
%XML
%HTML
Java
}

\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.6}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.8,0}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{
language=csh,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
numbers=left, % Ort der Zeilennummern
numberstyle=\tiny, % Stil der Zeilennummern
%stepnumber=2, % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
numbersep=5pt, % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
tabsize=2, % Groesse von Tabs
extendedchars=true, %
breaklines=true, % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
%keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
frame=b,
%keywordstyle=[1]\textbf, % Stil der Keywords
% keywordstyle=[2]\textbf, %
% keywordstyle=[3]\textbf, %
% keywordstyle=[4]\textbf, \sqrt{\sqrt{}} %
stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
showspaces=false, % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
showtabs=true, % Tabs anzeigen ?
xleftmargin=17pt,
framexleftmargin=17pt,
framexrightmargin=5pt,
framexbottommargin=4pt,
commentstyle=\color{blue},
morecomment=[s][\color{green}]{//}{},
%backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
showstringspaces=false, % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?
%morekeywords={__global__} % CUDA specific keywords
morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string},% list your attributes here
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
identifierstyle=\color{red},
}
%\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}

%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={blue}, textfont={blue}}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{8}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\lstset{       % keyword style
  language=csh,
  }

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
using System.Diagnostics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double; 
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        private void saveObjectToTemp()
        {
            //path to the tempfolder of this application.
            string path = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\temperatureapp";

            //check if the folder "temperatureapp" exist in the local temp folder (if not create it)
            bool folderExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!folderExist)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        private void saveObjectToTemp(object chart, string chartname)
        {
            //path to the tempfolder of this application.
            string path = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\temperatureapp";

            //check if the folder "temperatureapp" exist in the local temp folder (if not create it)
            bool folderExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!folderExist)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            Chart tmpChart = (Chart)chart;

            tmpChart.SaveImage(path + @"\" + chartname, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        }
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

The key words are not correctly identified and colored. Comments are also not identified and colored. (Comment lines in C# start with "//")

Any hints are taken gratefully by me!

Comment: The [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package, which works with [`Pygments`](http://pygments.org) will automatically prettyprint source code in the Visual Studio style if you tell it to use the `vs` option, but it can't break the lines to fit the page automatically.

Comment: hi @ChrisS I write an compile my texcode on [link](http://sharelatex.com) for minted I need a installation of Python and so on as far as I think this cant be realised with the online compiler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can have a try with my solution (which I found somewhere around this homepage I guess):

```
\setmonofont{Consolas} %to be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
\definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
captionpos=b,
%numbers=left, %Nummerierung
%numberstyle=\tiny, % kleine Zeilennummern
frame=lines, % Oberhalb und unterhalb des Listings ist eine Linie
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}
```

To be used with:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=a test for a C$^\sharp$ code, label=lst:test]
\end{lstlisting}
```

Keywords work just fine. However there are some things not working till now:

- `#region` is not set as a keyword. Tried that but didn't succeed.
- all bright blue stuff (objects) aren't recognized which will be a difficult point. Maybe there is a solution just to recognize e. g. `Math.` or other often used paths. As most objects are defined by the user, it would be a lot of handwork.
- quotation marks in strings don't fit the chosen font

Things which could get improved here (but I don't have the time to do it):

- set `///`, `<...>` and `<.../>` grey if it doesn't appear after `//` (where it should keep green). The XML comment itself should stay green.
- find objects and print them light blue. E. g. `private enum Object`, `public class Object : Object`, `private virtual Object` but `private virtual double` which are all keywords.
- find attributes and print them light blue. E. g. `[Serializable, CLSCompliant(false)]`.
- remember found objects and treat them the same way all over the document.
- Possibility to define objects manually or to recognize MSDN-objects like `Math.`

---

Looks like this until now:

[image]

Comment: If someone knows, why the quotation marks in my strings are not set in `Consolas`, please let me know.

Comment: maybe use `upquote=true`

Comment: Hi @LaRiFaRi, thx for your work I have two problems left. Here is a [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/51ec6b0c335f3d6370fd942b) to my solution. Problem 1 is the caption not going from left till end of the right side. Problem 2 is if a comment in the listing is going over two lines the frame gets colered green. I woud be happy do get hints to fix it. thank you!

Comment: Hi, that compiles for me. What are your two problems? If it is regarding the framebox and the captions, I can't help you at the moment (see the listings and caption manual...). Maybe do another question or edit your post above (not recommended as maybe nobody will see it).

Comment: @MaPePeR No, that doesn't work. But thx. In kimlivs ne MWE they look right. I will check the differences and edit it. (ah, she/he doesn't use consolas, but I want to use that further)

Comment: @kimliv Please notice, that I have updated colors and fontstyle to match exactly Visual Studio (2010). If you have the possibility, use the Consolas font!

Comment: Problem 2: rulecolor=\color{black}, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34688/lstlisting-how-to-set-code-color-and-frame-color

Comment: thx LaRiFaRi solved it

Answer (score 4):

There were several problems in your code. First of all i removed all the dead code and your comments, so i could point out my changes:

Your `morecomment`-definition
`morecomment=[s][\color{green}]{//}{}` should be `morecomment=[l][\color{green}]{//}`

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{8}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
```

i dont know a color named `8`. - changed it to `blue`

The additional `\lstset{ language=csh }` overwrote most of the formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{courier} %caused problems for me

\lstloadlanguages{% Check Dokumentation for further languages ...
C,
C++,
csh,
Java
}

\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.6}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.8,0}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{
language=csh,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\tiny, 
numbersep=5pt, 
tabsize=2, 
extendedchars=true, 
breaklines=true, 
frame=b,
stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily, 
showspaces=false, 
showtabs=true, 
xleftmargin=17pt,
framexleftmargin=17pt,
framexrightmargin=5pt,
framexbottommargin=4pt,
commentstyle=\color{green},
morecomment=[l]{//}, %use comment-line-style!
morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, %for multiline comments
showstringspaces=false, 
morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string},
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
identifierstyle=\color{red},
}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}} %changed \colorbox{8} to \colorbox{blue} cause 8 is not a color!
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

%remove that, it caused most of the problems
%\lstset{       % keyword style
%  language=csh,
%  }

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
using System.Diagnostics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double; 
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization;

namespace App
{
/*
Multiline comment
*/
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        private void saveObjectToTemp()
        {
            //path to the tempfolder of this application.
            string path = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\temperatureapp";

            //check if the folder "temperatureapp" exist in the local temp folder (if not create it)
            bool folderExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!folderExist)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        private void saveObjectToTemp(object chart, string chartname)
        {
            //path to the tempfolder of this application.
            string path = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\temperatureapp";

            //check if the folder "temperatureapp" exist in the local temp folder (if not create it)
            bool folderExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!folderExist)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            Chart tmpChart = (Chart)chart;

            tmpChart.SaveImage(path + @"\" + chartname, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        }
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for your solution and for finding my mistakes! I woud like to vote for your answer but i do not have enough reputation points so far.

Answer (score 2):

Since i wasn't able to find a really satisfying solution to C# listings in Latex , i invested a few hours and created a really perfect set of listing settings. I know this thread is really old but i hope it helps some dudes searching for a solution themselves. Have fun with my Example and leave an upvote if i was able to help :)

**I recreated the darkmode style from Visual Studio for C#. This is an example how it looks like:**

[image]

**This is the code in the header of the document before \begin{document}:**

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cascadia-code}
\usepackage{listings}

%Color scheme in Visual Studio darkmode
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}             
\definecolor{white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.97}      %background in Visual Studio
\definecolor{green}{cmyk}{0.6,0,0.84,0}       %comments in Visual Studio
\definecolor{blue}{cmyk}{0.65,0.33,0,0.05}       %keywords in Visual Studio
\definecolor{rose}{cmyk}{0,0.26,0.38,0}       %strings in Visual Studio
\definecolor{lavender}{cmyk}{0,0.42,0,0.1}   %if/else,switch/case etc. in Visual Studio
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.35,0,0,0}     %local variables in Visual Studio
\definecolor{aqua}{cmyk}{0.65,0,0.23,0}       %class types in Visual Studio
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.12,0,0.33,0.05} %enumerations and methods in Visual Studio

\lstset{
language=[Sharp]C,
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
rulesep=10pt,
xleftmargin=12pt,
framexleftmargin=-2pt,
framexrightmargin=-5pt,
showtabs=false,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=true,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
backgroundcolor=\color{darkgrey},
rulecolor=\color{darkgrey},
commentstyle=\color{green},
morecomment=[s][\color{green}]{/*+}{*/},
morecomment=[s][\color{green}]{/*-}{*/},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{white},
stringstyle=\color{rose},
frame=trbl,
framesep=5pt,
numbersep=7pt,
belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
%**********************
%ADD YOUR KEYWORDS HERE
%**********************
%-------------------------------------------
%keywords like string, int, false, true ...
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},
%-------------------------------------------
%keywords like if/else, switch/cas ...
emphstyle=\color{lavender},
emph={if, else, return, throw, switch, case},
%-------------------------------------------
%Collection of your local and global variables
emphstyle={[2]\color{lightblue}},
emph={[2]someLocalVariable, someGlobalVariable},
%-------------------------------------------
%Collection of your class types
emphstyle={[3]\color{aqua}},
emph={[3]SomeOwnClassType},
%-------------------------------------------
%Collection of your methods
emphstyle={[4]\color{lightgreen}},
emph={[4]ToLower},
}

%Optional
%Define a new floating environment to be able to generate an own list of codes in the document
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Codeexample]{myCode}
```

**This is the implementation of the code example inside the document:**

```
\begin{myCode} %Only when using the optional floating environment
\begin{lstlisting}
//This is a test for Latex listing C# with Visual Studio darkmode style
var someLocalVariable = "This is a test string";
if(someLocalVariable.ToLower() == "this is a test string")
{
    someGlobalVariable = new SomeOwnClassType();
}
\end{lstlisting}
\captionsetup{width=.95\textwidth}
\caption[This is the caption in the list of code examples]{This is the caption below the code example in the document}
\label{list:CodeExample}
\end{myCode}%Only when using the optional floating environment
```

**This is the implementation of the list of code examples:**

```
\begin{addmargin}[-1.5em]{0cm}
\listof{myCode}{\hspace{1.1em}List of Codes}
\end{addmargin}
```